# ProviderNotFoundException - Error: Could not find the correct Provider<NewAntProvider> above this MenuTiposAnt Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I am trying to access a provider and I'm getting this error, I can't figure out what am I doing wrong here.
Here is part of the code, I tried to resume it and leave only what is related to the problem. I think there's something wrong in the stateful widget class but I'm not sure.
My apologies in advance if it's an obvious error, I'm new to this.

**The code**

`new_ant_page.dart`

```
class NewAntPage extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String routeName = 'NewAntPage';
  const NewAntPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
            appBar: const AppbarCustom(),
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            body: Column(
              children: [
                // Some code
                ChangeNotifierProvider(
                    create: (_) => NewAntProvider(),
                    child: const FormNewAnt()),
              ],
            )));
  }
}


class FormNewAnt extends StatelessWidget {
  const FormNewAnt({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final newAntProvider = Provider.of<NewAntProvider>(context);
    return Expanded(
        child: Column(
        children: [
          const AddAnt(),
          // Some code
        ],
      ));
  }
}


class AddAnt extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddAnt({super.key});

  @override
  State<AddAnt> createState() => _AddAntState();
}

class _AddAntState extends State<AddAnt> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final newAntProvider = Provider.of<NewAntProvider>(context);

    return ElevatedButtonCustom(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
        onPressed: (!newAntProvider.isLoading)
            ? () async {
                showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (context) => AlertDialogCustom(
                          title: '',
                          content: [
                            Form(
                                key:
                                    newAntProvider.formKeyAnt,
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    const MenuTiposAnt(),
                                    // Some code
                                  ],
                                ))
                          ],
                          actions: [
                          // Some code
                          ],
                        ));
              }
            : () {},
        text: 'Add');
  }
}


class MenuTiposAnt extends StatelessWidget {
  const MenuTiposAnt({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final newAntProvider = Provider.of<NewAntProvider>(context); // HERE I GET THE ERROR

    return FutureStatesBuilder<List<TipoAntDto>?>(
        future: TipoAntService.tipoAntService.tipos,
        someAction: (value) {
          return DropDownButtonCustom<TipoAntDto>(
            label: 'Tipo',
            labelColor: Colors.black,
            items: value ?? [],
            value: newAntProvider.tipoAnt,
            onChanged: (value) => newAntProvider.tipoAnt = value,
          );
        });
  }
}
```

**Provider**

`new_ant_provider.dart`

```
class NewAntProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  GlobalKey<FormState> formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  GlobalKey<FormState> formKeyAnt = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  TipoAntDto? _tipoAnt;

  bool _isLoading = false;


  TipoAntDto? get tipoAnt => _tipoAnt;
  set tipoAnt(TipoAntDto? value) {
    _tipoAnt = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  bool get isLoading => _isLoading;
  set isLoading(bool value) {
    _isLoading = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

**Custom widget**

`alert_dialog_custom.dart`

```
class AlertDialogCustom extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final List<Widget> content;
  final List<Widget>? actions;
  const AlertDialogCustom({super.key, required this.title, required this.content, this.actions});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: Row(
        children: [
          Image(
              image: const AssetImage('assets/imgs/logo.png'),
              height: Dimens.dimens70),
          SizedBox(width: Dimens.dimens30),
          Expanded(
              child: BodyText(
            text: title,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
          )),
        ],
      ),
      titlePadding: EdgeInsets.all(Dimens.dimens25),
      content: Scrollbar(
        thumbVisibility: true,
        thickness: 6.0,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(Dimens.dimens25),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: content,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      actions: actions,
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    );
  }
}
```